# How to show current and updated (to the second) DateTime.Now C#

Tags: c#

How would I make this code show the current time, accurately to the second?

```
using System;

namespace TestCode
{
class DisplayTime
{
static void Main()
 {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(" Blah Blah Blah ");
    Console.WriteLine(now);
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
}
```

}

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(now.ToString());`

Comment: Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); or something like that at least. The letters inside the to string field represent different outputs. A list should display when you begin to type them telling you what they are, depending on your IDE of course.

Comment: @Savlon yes, you are [right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: [Swearing is not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites).  Please edit your question.

Comment: Really embarrassed about that guys... sorry. My buddy and I were learning a bit of the basics together, and we had a laugh over that.  

Thank you very much @Savlon 

First time on the site, you guys are quick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ToString()` has already done it for you.

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't swear."); //change this too
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString());
```

You can also make it print in specific format as you want to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't swear."); //change this too
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff)); //up to milliseconds
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more choices.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Very quick!

Comment: @RolledUhhp good. ;) and just FYI, MSDN is a great reference site for C#

Comment: @RolledUhpp And MSDN can be accessed simply by pressing F1 while the cursor is on the code (like on DateTime, on ToString, etc). It's almost like MS paid people to organize the documentation to be searchable easily

Comment: Thanks @Martheen! 
It's my second day with the language, and programming in general. While I have a working knowledge of computers I'm feeling a bit stranded in the ocean - overwhelmed. 

I've been trying to search out as much as I can on my own, but I can't find any examples that are EXACT matches to what I have already, and even a few characters difference is really throwing me off. 

I'm trying to get there!

Comment: @RolledUhhp Good for you. Yes every single character is important in programming. Try to always use snippets to avoid mistype, and Edit-Format Document regularly to see if there's any structural mishaps

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

        string Time = time.ToString("mm");


        Console.WriteLine($"{time}");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It will not show the milliseconds like the above person said, but perhaps it will do.

Comment: These are all working to show the Date and Time in different formats, but it is not "Ticking" or actively keeping track of time... It's still only showing the time at execution.